# createTimer() replacement in eloquent

Tags: ros, c++, clock, timer

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In ROS1 we can simply do:

```
ros::Timer timer = nh.createTimer(ros::Duration(0.1), timerCallback);
```

This gives us a tick approximately every 100 ms of ROS time. In ROS2, particularly in Eloquent, there is no similar API as far as I can determine, and the only references I find mention Ardent APIs that have been removed. However, for this code:

```
rclcpp::Clock ros_clock(RCL_ROS_TIME);
```

This returns a ROS time-based clock, but I cannot see an obvious way to go from there to a timer that ticks every simulated 100 milliseconds. `rclcpp::create_wall_timer()` exists, but not the more generic `rclcpp::create_timer(rclccp::Clock, duration, callback)`. How can I replicate the ROS1 behaviour in ROS2?

---

**EDIT**: Studying the API, the best I can find is something like this:

```
rclcpp::Clock ros_clock(RCL_ROS_TIME);
rclcpp::timer::GenericTimer<??typeof my_callback??, ros_clock> ros_timer(10ms, std::bind(&my_callback, this));
n.get_node_timers_interface()->add_timer(ros_timer, n.get_callback_groups());
```

This seems a very long-winded way to do this, though!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/353436/createtimer()-replacement-in-eloquent/) by [KenYN](https://answers.ros.org/users/25651/kenyn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 541 on 2020-05-27

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you found `Node::create_wall_timer`?

Docs: http://docs.ros2.org/eloquent/api/rclcpp/classrclcpp_1_1Node.html#a72bcd0268e23fafda8766b01f1ce624f

---

Originally posted by [Mbuijs](https://answers.ros.org/users/33718/mbuijs/) with karma: 247 on 2020-06-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [KenYN](https://answers.ros.org/users/25651/kenyn/) on 2020-06-10**:
I did eventually; I'd been looking at the `beta3` documentation instead of `eloquent`...

**Comment by [Mbuijs](https://answers.ros.org/users/33718/mbuijs/) on 2020-06-11**:
It's quite annoying that in search results the old documentation typically appears higher than eloquent (and now foxy), so now I usually add `eloquent` in front of my searches in an attempt to find the right version straight away.